# Analise de código em produção

Tags: php, linux, apache, desempenho

Olá,

Gostaria de saber se há alguma ferramenta open source para eu analisar o uso de memória/processamento alocado por meus métodos em produção.

Gostaria disso para saber quais métodos precisam de atenção e melhorias, e assim diminuir o uso de recursos por minhas aplicações.

Meus ambientes de produção são compostos do php-5.6 ou php-7 (depende da aplicação), nginx como proxy reverso, Apache2 por trás do NGINX (por limitações em algumas aplicações) e Linux (Ubuntu/CentOS) como S.O.

Comment: Você pode ver algumas informações com o [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) (livre) e o [blackbird](https://blackfire.io/) (pago) ambos fazem profiling.

Comment: No caso do XDEBUG ele não vai deixar minha aplicação mais lenta?

Comment: Qualquer profiler vai deixar sua aplicação (talvez até bem) lenta, você executar só para detectar os gargalos depois desliga, faz as devidas modificações e liga novamente para ver se surtiu efeitou ou não.

Comment: Ah sim entendi, achei que poderia haver algo como o Sentry (que faz análise de erros) de maneira que pudesse ficar ligado em produção sem afetar performance... (mas achei muito mágico no caso do profiling) vou fazer uns testes.

Comment: No caso do Xdebug, você executa aquele trecho de código e ele vai medindo quanto tempo **cada operação** (chamadas de métodos/funções) levou para ser realizada e quantia de mémoria alocada. Depois ele gera um arquivo com essas informações é necessário uma outra ferramenta para analizar esse log, o [webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind) é um exemplo existem outras opções.

Comment: Open-Source não sei. Existe o NewRelic e afins, que monitoram todo o servidor e a aplicação. É capaz de lista o tempo médio de resposta, quais foram os mais lentos e porque foram, qual função consumiu mais tempo para ser processado,até mesmo a query que demorou para ser processada e, lógico, também informa erros de execução... Ele pode normalmente é mantido ligado "para sempre". Porém é paga.

Answer (score 0):

Mas no caso, **você precisa mensurar o pico de acesso nesses Servidores Web**, com **rrdtool**, **cacti** + **mrtg**, você vai ter os gráficos desses acessos.

Depois tem a velocidade do disco e quantidade de memoria ram e tamanho e quantidade de acesso ao banco de dados.

Quando você tiver esses gráficos você vai ter uma ideia do contexto geral que está ocorrendo no Servidor como um todo, tente partir desse ponto primeiro.

Claro isso foi uma sugestão, minha que cuidei por quase 10 anos de ambientes de hospedagem, espero que consiga ajudar, qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: Olá Nilton, mas eu gostaria de id identificar gargalos no meu código exemplo (meu método setPontuacao aloca x de memória demora em média x tempo para ser executado) com base nisso posso melhorar meus códigos